# vba disable drag and drop enable fill handle

Tags: excel, vba

I want to disable drag and drop but in doing so it is also disabling fill handle, which I don't want to disable.

Currently using following

```
Application.CellDragAndDrop = False '<<also cancels fill handle
ws.Protect "Password", Contents:=True, DrawingObjects:=False, AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, userinterfaceonly:=True
```

Fill handle is a copy/paste function, & I can manually still copy/paste, so not sure I understand why DragAndDrop, which is a cut/paste operation, should cause this issue.

So is there some way to disable DragAndDrop but still allow fill handle to work? Thanks.

EDIT: for reference, fill handle:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/copy-a-formula-by-dragging-the-fill-handle-in-excel-for-mac-dd928259-622b-473f-9a33-83aa1a63e218

Comment: Isn't "fill down" a drag & drop operation (albeit with custom double-click behavior on the handle)? I'm not sure how you came to conclude that "fill handle is a copy/paste function", is it because it clears the clipboard?

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to small handle that allows copy/paste, which I guess is same/similar to the fill down operation. Or is that the same thing? I just kind of figured they're copy/paste operation? Edit: don't care so much for the double-click fill behavior, just being able to access the handle on cell itself.

Comment: Well if you *drag* that handle down, you get the *fill* behavior. My hunch is that it's a  D&D operation, not C&P - IOW you can't disable D&D without losing autofill.

Comment: Right thanks, so any possible way to work around that then if that is indeed the case? As that's mildly annoying & doesn't make sense, because I can still CTRL+C, CTRL+P.

Comment: Short of hijacking the message pump and reprogramming Excel, I'm not sure there's a solution there - why disable D&D anyway?

Comment: Need to disable D&D because if I don't I need to account for possible #REF! issues that users may invoke on linked cells, accidentally or otherwise. I could edit my question to include catching & overriding D&D op?

Comment: I'm guessing that accounting for the possible #REF! issues is going to be easier, and in the long term, much better for both you and your users. Changing the behavior of the host application to account for deficiencies in the code, validation, or to attempt and forestall user error isn't a real solution.

Comment: @Comintern I've contemplated that too & will have to failing this, but was looking at these options first as this will be an easier to deal with, as data where #REF! may happen is dynamic & expanding.